# Отправка запроса из JS в Python

Tags: javascript, python, localhost

Имеется локальный http сервер, запускаемый из Python http.server. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как обработать тело запроса в скрипте Python и выдать его обратно для дальнейшей обработки. Библиотеки Python стандартные для python 3.12. На работе нет возможности поставить Flask или какие-либо другие доп. библиотеки. Для примера накидал форму.
Не прошу накидать полноценный код, прошу указать направление. Можно под Python 3.9

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <script defer src="js/script.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" class="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
      <button type = "button" class="btn" onclick="send()">Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    function send(){
      response = null;
      let name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
      let lastname = document.querySelector('.lastname').value
      let user = {
        'name': name,
        'lastname': lastname
      }
      return fetch('cgi-bin/test.py', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
      })
      .then(resp => {
        response = resp
        console.log (response)
        return response
      })
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: А вы проверяли? `Flask` обычно есть во всех дистрибутивах `Python`, даже самых базовых. Я не помню, чтобы его приходилось отдельно куда-то ставить. А его если и нет, то есть простой сервер `http.server` в стандартных встроенных библиотеках: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html